# Unable to connect to Apache remotely

Tags: centos, linux-networking, httpd

I've created a new instance of Apache's httpd process on my development server for testing purposes. The machine is running Centos 6.8.

**I'm able to connect to the web server locally through curl but unable to connect externally.**

```
# curl 127.0.0.1:1500
    {"message":"Hello World!"}
```

I've updated my iptables to allow new TCP connections over port 1500 - currently my rules are as follows:

```
# iptables -nL
    Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
    target     prot opt source               destination
    ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           state NEW tcp dpt:1500

    Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
    target     prot opt source               destination

    Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
    target     prot opt source               destination
```

I've also tried allowing access through SELinux:

```
# semanage port -l | grep 1500
    http_port_t                    tcp      1500, 8080, 80, 81, 443, 488, 8008, 8009, 8443, 9000
```

Any assistance in debugging this issue would be greatly appreciated, as I'm not sure what else to try.

Edit as per Simon's comment:

```
# netstat -nlp | grep 1500
    tcp        0      0 :::1500                     :::*                       LISTEN      23117/httpd_dev
```

Comment: What is the output of `netstat -nlp | grep 80`?

Comment: What is the problem you are having? You need to be specific.

Comment: @SimonGreenwood, the apache server is actually running on 1500 - I've updated the main post to contain the output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems (from the comments) that an upstream GCP firewall is blocking access.

---

Check and see if you httpd server is listening on your external IP address, something like

```
netstat -tnlp | grep :1500
```

Should give an output like

```
tcp      0    0 :::1500                :::*                  LISTEN  2295/httpd
```

If it's listening on all addresses If it's only listening on 127.0.0.1 the you'll see something like

```
tcp      0    0 127.0.0.1:25           0.0.0.0:*             LISTEN      2297/httpd
```

and you should adjust the listen directive in your httpd configuration appropriately.

Comment: I've updated the main post to contain the output of the first command. It appears to be configured correctly.

Comment: What is the exact error message you are getting from whatever it is you are trying to connect to your server with.

Comment: No connection is established resulting in a time out.

Comment: Then you are connecting to the wrong IP address or there is an upstream firewall causing problems.

Comment: I have the correct IP address, and I am unaware of any upstream firewalls (Google Compute cloud system). I have other instances of Apache running on this server which is why I'm using port 1500 - perhaps this port is being blocked because it's non standard? I'll try setting it to something else.

Comment: Doesn't GCP have a firewall in front of your instance ?

Comment: You are correct, I'll look into this. Thank you for the assistance.